# Declare a pointer of type base class, but then instantiate it by pointing to a child class. Is this good programming practice?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to figure my head around polymorphism and pointers and am following some wonderful videos explaining it ([hyperlink if you really care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wql9F2O0unM&list=PL9xky4LydsuXWMV6nzOfnCEIQujfxGPzr&index=11))

He declares `class A` and `class B` which inherits from A.

But to instantiate an object of B he does so like this:

```
A* b = new B;
```

and it works fine (and he continues to use that method when creating more complex classes, a vector array of base type Shape that contains child classes Square, Circle etc. i.e.

```
std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
shapes.push_back(new Circle.........
shapes.push_back(new Rectangle.......
```

It is possible, but is it totally fine (and even recommended) to declare a pointer to an object of a base class, but then instantiate it by pointing to its child class??

I guess I just answered my own question, that the benefit comes from being able to manage collections of different objects by referring to them by their parent class? Is that correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Good practice? If you need the polymorphic behaviour, yes. If can make do without it, even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but is it totally fine (and even recommended) to declare a pointer to an object of a base class, but then instantiate it by pointing to its child class?

When you use

```
A* ptr = new B();
```

instead of

```
B* ptr = new B();
```

you are losing just a small amount of information. You cannot use any member functions that are defined in `B` but not in `A`.  Please note that it is perfectly fine to use `virtual` member functions declared in `A` but implemented in `B`.

If that small amount of loss is OK in your use case, then there is no harm in using `A* ptr =`. If you would like to be able to preserve the `B`-ness of the pointer so you can use it to access members that are specific to `B`, it will be necessary to use `B* ptr =`.

---

There is a guiding principles about using pointer/reference types:

1. When defining a function interface, use a pointer/referene type that is as higher up in the class hierarchy as you can get away with to implement the function.

   Given

   ```
   struct Shape { ... };
   struct Circle : Shape { ... };
   ```

   don't use `Circle` in the interface of a function if everything you need in the function can be obtained from a `Shape`.

   When you add the next sub-class of `Shape`,

   ```
   struct Rectangle : Shape { ... };
   ```

   that function can be used with a `Rectangle` too without any change.
2. When defining a pointer/reference, use a type that preserves as much information as possible.

   If there is a function

   ```
   Circle* someFunction();
   ```

   then, use

   ```
   Circle* circlePtr = someFunction();
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   Shape* shapePtr = someFunction();
   ```

   You can use `circlePtr` for wherever you need a `Shape*` but you won't be able to use `shapePtr` wherever you need a `Circle*`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You partly answered your question, but there can also be other reasons.

Polymorphism is so you can keep some things abstract. Imagine, for instance, code like this:

```
Person *actor;

if (occupation == 'nerd') {
    actor = new NerdPerson();
}
else if (occupation == 'mortician') {
    actor = new MorticianPerson();
}
...

actor->printOccupation();
```

Clearly that's a made up reason. So it MIGHT be about collections of something, but that's only one reason.

Comment: I see. Great point. Just for clarity, occupation is a string?

Comment: @aName ya. It's pseudo-code, though. My main point is that there can be other reasons. Programming is complicated, and there's rarely any single reason why you would use a particular language construct.